# How to ignore starred command (such as \section*) with latexdiff?

Tags: sectioning, starred-version, latexdiff

I try to ignore changes of `\section*` in `latexdiff`, and while I am able to do so for `\section`, the same does not work for `\section*`.

This is `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \section{Hello}
    Hi

    \section*{Bye}
    Cya
\end{document}
```

This is `b.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    Hi

    Cya
\end{document}
```

`latexdiff --exclude-textcmd="section" a.tex b.tex > c.tex` correctly excludes changes in `\section`; but replacing `section` by `section*` does not work for `\section*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try escaping the asterisk using a backslash:

```
latexdiff --exclude-textcmd="section\*" a.tex b.tex > c.tex
```